# How to take screenshot programmatically along with current date printed on it?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have taken screenshot programmatically for a scroll view in xcode. But the problem i am facing is, i need to take screenshot along with present date in it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Before taking screenshot, put one label with current date, and remove it after taking screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can add a text to an image. Try this with the date as string. Once you taken the screenshot pass it to the below method and use the output image. Modify the below method for your convenience.

```
//Add text to UIImage
-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1{
    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height; 
    //lon = h - lon;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

    char* text = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];// "05/05/09";
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1);


    //rotate text
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( -M_PI/4 ));

    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 4, 52, text, strlen(text));

    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
}
```

[Source](http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/05/05/Add-text-to-image-%28UIImage%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the EXIF meta data to record the date (it's probably already in there). I guess an embedded date in the image is harder to fake, though.